# Fix missing "<" key in swiss french keyboard layout

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am installing arch linux, and I have the following problem:

I changed the keyboard mapping to fr_CH as I am using a swiss french keyboard. A lot of keys work, but a lot don't, including the "<" key, which is pretty essential to use in a terminal.

Some other keys behave strangely, in the general form that they simply aren't recognized, i.e. they type nothing.

It is pretty natural that the accented keys don't work in the terminal (at least I hope so), but for the others, how can I fix the keyboard layout?

Comment: Accented keys should work.

Comment: Should they? I can't be sure. I'm using the fullscreen terminal (not sure how it's called, but the login one, the one without x running), so maybe the glyphs for the accented letters just can't be rendered. The fact is, taking into account all the visible effects of their use, they don't seem to work, and that's worrying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I omitted to mention, as I thought it was irrelevant, was that I was running linux on QEMU. The fact that the angle brackets and the accented keys were ignored seems to have been caused by a bug in it. Switching to Virtualbox has fixed the problem.